# list comprehension for empty list python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have an python 3 code as follow:

```
a = []
b = [[0] * len(a[0]) for _ in range(len(a))]
```

The above code works fine, but the follow code does not work:

```
a = []
m, n = len(a), len(a[0])
```

`len(a[0])` apppears in both codes, why the list comprehension does not through `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range(len(a))` in this case is essentially `range(0)`, which is an empty range:

```
>>> list(range(0))
[]
```

Because the collection being iterated over is empty, the comprehension never runs, so `a[0]` is never evaluated.

It's similar to how this loop prints nothing:

```
for _ in []:
    print("SOME TEXT!")
```

`[]` is empty, so the `for` loop never iterates.

With `m, n = len(a), len(a[0])` however, `a[0]` is run regardless of the length of `a`, so `a[0]` is evaluated, and you get an error.